# How can you improve the speed of the WpAllImport for updating prices?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, wpallimport

I have installed the Wp All Import plugin on my WordPress website. I am using it to update the product prices. All the prices are of type External, as it is an affiliate website. I have around 44,000 products and the way I update them using the plugin is downloading the CSV using the URL option and setting the plugin to only update "regular price" and "sale price".

On the server side, it doesn't seem to be any issue. As the import is running, it doesn't even reach 10% of its characteristics. The `WP_OPTIONS` table has only 7000 elements, so it's not bloated, as it mentions in the plugin docs. I also scheduled the import jobs on the cron in the server and i am running the processing URL every two minutes.

It processes around 2000 products in 4.5 hours and that is too slow. I can't find any more advice on how to improve the update speed. I didn't think it will be a problem, as I am only updating two fields: regular price and sale price.

Comment: Did you try to run your import on https://www.wpallimport.com/debug ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It worked a lot better. The problem is I don't know how to put my finger on the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say.

Did you try disabling the `do_action` calls in `wp_insert_post` during import feature (as [the docs](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/troubleshooting/slow-imports/) recommend)?

> In Manage Imports ▸ Import Settings ▸ Advanced Options you can enable the Increase speed by disabling do_action calls in wp_insert_post during import feature.

Another thing you can try is to run an import for 1 record and print all queries to the log file. Could give you a clue. More info in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/how-to-print-the-excuted-sql-right-after-its-execution).

Comment: Yes, I disabled that option. I know it's hard to say, been researching for a week now trying to give it a little boost.
I will try printing the query to the log file, see what I can find. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Good luck. You can get another opinion by filing a ticket with plugin support: https://www.wpallimport.com/support they're very nice folks :)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing and talking with the hosting support team, I managed to lower the processing time. Initially, as stated in the question, it was around 2000 products updated in 4.5H. Now it updates 2400 products in 2H.

What I did is add the code below to the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1, E=noconntimeout:1]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps someone struggling with the same problem :)

Don't know if it can get better than this, but I will try and update here if I manage to do anything else.

All the best!

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing. What does it do? P.S.: I also found this guide: https://gist.github.com/trey8611/72fec5969651d5272fcb85f99b09b8bb

Comment: https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cp/cpanel/long-run-script/